# Increase Duration of WPF PopUp Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a WPF PopUp control that I'm using to show a menu overlay and I'm using the default fade animation.  However I would like to make the animation take slightly longer to complete.

Is there anyway I can do that in the XAML?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the relevant xaml code here? Otherwise, you can look at these links to get started with animation in xaml -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx

[How to set WPF animation BeginTime based on properties (Top/Tabstop) of the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714062/how-to-set-wpf-animation-begintime-based-on-properties-top-tabstop-of-the-contr)