# WPF Popup : open with animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am using a wpf popup control.

```
<Popup x:Name="tabHolder" IsOpen="False" 
    PopupAnimation="Slide" Placement="Bottom" 
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainWidgetWindow}">
    <Grid Height="105" Width="315" />
</Popup>
```

Here I have set popup animation property to slide. But when it opens, it doesn't animate. Do I have to add any other configuration for popup to open with animation option slide?

I am using .net framework version 3.5.

Comment: Did you set the time for the animation?

Comment: @Noctis: Looks like I have not. I have not much experience in animation of wpf. I thought by setting animation type it would work.

Comment: @Noctis: Thanks for the insight to pop and answer. Its working. Can I set duration for this animation?

Comment: have a look at what this guy said in his [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7704855/1698987)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From MSDN

> A Popup can only animate when the `AllowsTransparency` property is set to `true`. This requires the application that creates the Popup control to run with full trust.
> If the `PlacementTarget` is animated, the Popup will not be animated.

XAML should look like

```
<DockPanel  Width="500" Background="Aqua">
  <Popup Placement="Center" PlacementRectangle="0,0,30,50"  
          IsOpen ="True" AllowsTransparency="True"
          PopupAnimation="Fade">
    <TextBlock Background="Purple">Popup Text</TextBlock>
  </Popup>
</DockPanel>
```

And you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.popupanimation(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Popup will animate  if you have set AllowsTransparency true.
like -

```
AllowsTransparency="True".
```